# is this a reasonable target load for SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, embedded

We are in analysis mode for an embedded Linux system which will use an ARM9 processor around 400 megahertz.

It would have multiple sensors and we would need to write logs to a SQLite 3 database. We estimate the maximum load imaginable would be between 100 and 200 database inserts per second.

Is this reasonable or should we go have our heads examined?

Comment: Please update (edit) the question or leave comments if you have follow up questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is unreasonable to write logs into db. SQL databases are developed with assumption of frequently reading and not writing.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Mtr.

There is a requirement to be able to search later through the logs with filters, and to display web based graphs (likely with PHP) using the search results.

So it is not strictly a matter of dumping info into a file no one will ever look at.

Cheers,
Bert